# How to use sql statement in entity framework to return the list of record

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have the the database like in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvtGy.jpg) and the code below:

```
Int32 row_count = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<Int32>("select count(*) from Categories").FirstOrDefault<Int32>() ;
```

I want to write the code that is the same or similar to the code below:

```
private void FillDataToList(string Prefix)
    {
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    using (var ctx=new CambbusPOSEntities()){
      foreach(obj in ctx.SQLManager.Where(a=>a.Entity==Prefix)){
        var query = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<List>(obj.SQL).ToList();
        bs.DataSource = query;
      }
}
```

}

But it show the error:

Using the generic type 'System.collections.Generic.List' requires 1 type arguments

So do we have another way that use with sql statement in entity?Because I want to store all sql statement in database. Thank you

Comment: "it show the error" - may we know what "it" is and what "the error" is? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: @Hans Kesting I edit my question already.Could you please help me to solve this problem..

Answer (score 1):

You should create one Table model to contain all Property of that Table. Example:

```
var query = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<Categories>("select * from Categories").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You apparently want a generic way to get results from a sql query that you specify at runtime. Entity Framework wants to use specific types (known at compile time) that you cannot provide in this way. Also you are ignoring the "query build" features of EF using LINQ. So why use EF?

Maybe you could use an "oldfashioned" `DataSet`. Then you can fill a generic data structure with the results of any query you provide at runtime.

See for instance [Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx).

Comment: thank for your idea but my manager want me to use with Entity Framework.

Comment: Entity Framework wants to fill strongly typed data entities - *you* will have to tell it what type to use and then only use a query that will provide data for that type.